# Need help in expect conditions, as I need to save JSON and check the length of the object in request call

Tags: json, asynchronous, request, protractor

I'm working on Protractor automation, where I need to save JSON after few activities in browser. Then I'm checking the length of the object but I have seen that no console or expect conditions are working when given in setTimeout.

The console and expect statements are working if not given in setTimeout but the JSON response is asynchronous even before the activities.

test_speck.js :

```
it('Verify the json', function () {
 this.commonfunc.checkJSON();
}
```

common_functions.js :

```
checkJSON: function(){
setTimeout(function(){
 var request = require('request');

 request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function (error, response, body){ 
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
   var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log('Length of importedJSON : ' + importedJSON.length);
   expect(importedJSON.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  }
 }
},90000);
}
```

Actual : The spec is being passed without any console.log or expect statements.
Expected : Console and expect statments to be worked

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback and it should work.

```
describe('SO Question 58726564', () => {
  it('Verify the json', (done) => {
    var request = require('request');

    request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('Length of importedJSON : ' + importedJSON.length);
        expect(importedJSON.length).toBeGreaterThan(10);
      }
      done()
    })
  })
})
```